# Python: Random 0 1 generator with certain probabilities in a list or matrix

Tags: python, arrays, random, probability

I need to put commas between 0 and 1 so I can make a histogram of the data.

This y my distribution but is there a way to put commas like this in the array  [0,0,0,1,0] or a direct way to make the histogram from it?

```
#20 is the number of columns that we will have
for x in np.arange(0.05 , 1 , 0.2):
    t = np.array(np.random.rand( 20 ) < x , int)
    print (t)
```

And I get this output

```
[0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
[1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1]
[1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Please explain what commas have to do with histograms, and what a histogram with only two possible values (0 and 1) would look like.  If you wrote some code to print an array with commas in between the values instead of spaces, how would that get you any closer to plotting a histogram?

Answer (score 0):

You want to `join` your elements with a comma, but to do that you have to convert them to `str` first.

I came up with the following code

```
for x in np.arange(0.05 , 1 , 0.2):
    t = np.array(np.random.rand( 20 ) < x , int)
    joined = ",".join(map(str, t))
    print(f"[{joined}]")
```